# ngIf does not show md-select on ngModel change

Tags: angular

This was working until Angular `4.3.2+` - no idea why the Md-Select is not showing. `{{ selected }}` spits out `category`; I am sure of this.

```
<md-select formControlName="category" name="category"  
      placeholder="Categories" *ngIf="selected === 'category'">
    <md-option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [value]="cat.value">
        {{ cat.viewValue }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

When I inspect the `md-select` element, it has a random `display: none` inline.

Comment: What if you move the `*ngIf` out to an enclosing `ng-container`, does that make any difference?

Comment: Nope, I've tried both scenarios. :/

Comment: ngIf shouldn't create a display: none. Is it possible your css changed and the angular version change is a red herring?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you were on the right path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with `AngularJS ^4.0.0` and/or `Material`

Scenario: If an `*ngIf` is placed on or is a direct parent of the `Material` component, the component gets a `display: none` as a inline style.

## Solution 1

`.parent-class .md-component { display: inline-block !important }`

## Solution 2

Place any element as a direct parent of the `md-component` - even adding a `<span>` tag fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your explanation of the problem, you're misunderstanding what `ngIf` does. `display: none` does not come from `ngIf`. `ngIf` completely **removes or adds** an element to the DOM; it does not hide or show it with a CSS property.

If the condition passed to `ngIf` evaluates to `false`, or a falsy value, you wouldn't even see the element in the dev tools.

Comment: that is what is confusing me so much. the html is not there, then when it DOES show the html, there is a `display: none` inline on the md-select element

Comment: That is something else, not the `ngIf`. You're looking at the wrong part of code by inspecting the ngIf.